# Pass prop through to a component's child element that doesn't expose it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a `DateTimeSelector` component from a library which encapsulates an html `Input` element. I would like to make the Input `readonly` but `DateTimeSelector` does not expose a prop to do this. Is there a way to achieve this without, of course, requiring a change to the library component? I'm wondering if this can maybe be manipulated in a manner similar to how inner class styles can be manipulated using css.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, no

Comment: If it's in the DOM then chances are you *can* get to it and set attributes, but direct DOM manipulation is an anti-pattern in React.

Comment: What properties does the `DateTimeSelector` have? Many times there is an object with configuration, that would be attached to the element inside.